# putting function values in meshgrid format in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have coordinate vectors X and Y and corresponding vector of function values Z. I need to plot a surface Z(X,Y), and I need to put Z values on a regular mesh, right now X and Y define points distributed irregularly. What is the best way to do it in matlab?

Thanks!

Comment: use `griddata` to interpolate your data

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function such as `z=f(x,y)` then you could use `fsurf()`.

`fsurf(@(x,y) x^2+y^2);`

Or else, if you have data points then you could use `surf()`

```
[x, y]=meshgrid(-5:0.1:5);
z = x.^2 + y.^2;
mesh(x,y,z);
```

You could specify the axis as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

Zinter = scatteredInterpolant(Xs,Ys,Z) %defines interpolant for scattered data and allows to calculate values of z for any point

Comment: Please add proper code formatting to your code snippets. A link to the documentation for `scatteredInterpolant` might be helpful as well, for folks who aren't familiar with it.